# Using `1>&- 2>&- &' as an alias after a shell command

Tags: bash, io-redirection, alias, stdout, stderr

To run a program with `bash` in background, with no text output, it is possible to use: `1>&- 2>&- &`. I would like to define an alias for this. However, if I write in `.bashrc`

```
alias nooutput = '1>&- 2>&- &'
```

the string `nooutput` is interpreted by the shell as an additional argument (for example, a filename) for the executable I would like to run. Also, auto-completion seems not to act on `nooutput`: it I press `noou`, for example, and then <kbd>tab</kbd>, it does not auto-complete.

How to use an alias in this case?

---

I'm using `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` on Ubuntu `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` with Linux `5.4.0-91-generic x86_64`, but, if there is a solution, I would like it to be as general as possible, not related to a specific `bash` version or system architecture.

Comment: Closing the standard output streams could cause a command to fail. It would be better to redirect them to `/dev/null` as one usually does. For example, `echo hello 1>&- 2>&-` fails and sets `$?` to 1.  That final `&` seems unrelated to the "no output" aspect of what you want to do.

Comment: @they Thanks for your suggestions. As specified in the beginning of my post, i would like ``to run a program with `bash` *in background*, with no text output`. It is unrelated to the "no output", but it is a requirement, too.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, [Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the ***first word*** of a simple command.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) not at the middle or end of that command, so when you are trying to use your aliases at the at the end of a command like *`myCommand myAlias`*, it won't work as mentioned earlier why, and aliases should come as the first word of a command like *`myAlias myCommand`*;

but the background running operator as you used in `1>&- 2>&- &` cannot come at the start of the command (cannot do `& myCommand`), so you cannot use `&` like that in your aliases.

second problem is that, there should not be a spaces around aliases name and alias text.

you need `alias nooutput='1>&- 2>&- '`; then run as following:

```
nooutput myCommand &
```

*Note:
For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.*

Answer (score 1):

Bash only supports aliases in the first word position (or after another alias, if the first one ends with a space). However, in zsh, you could make that a *global alias*, those are expanded from any position.

```
zsh% alias -g nooutput='1>&- 2>&- &'
% (echo foo; sleep 12) nooutput
[1] 15058
...
```

Though at least my version of zsh doesn't tab-complete the alias name other than from the first position, I didn't look if that can be configured.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd prefer to use `bash`. Your comments to the other answer are very useful, if you want you can integrate them here as an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use functions:

```
run_bg() { eval $@ > /dev/null & }
```

you can make it permanent by adding this function definition line to `~/.bashrc`.

Usage:

```
run_bg echo "hey"
```

Comment: Using `eval` would make the function expect a command line to be further evaluated, that is, something like `run_bg somemcd "file name"` would not work, the user would need to enter `run_bg 'somecmd "file name"'` (or equivalent), and similarly using variables that might contain special characters would also require care. (You'd probably want to quote them so that they'd be expanded by the`eval`, not the outer shell.) For that, it'd be better to use `"$*"`, since it makes it clear that we're passing a single string, and avoids word-splitting and globbing issues from the unquoted `$@`.

Comment: Though for the use, you could probably just use `run_bg() { "$@" 1>&- 2>&- & }`. 
`"$@"` expands to all words the function got as arguments, separately and without splitting, so you could just use `run_bg somecmd "file name"`. (Not sure why the subshell should be needed, but if you do need it, just `run_bg() ( ... )` would do.) Of course `"$@"` wouldn't work with compound commands etc., that's where'd you'd need the `eval`.

Comment: If eminfedar could modify its answer and/or you could make your own answer with these considerations, it would be great.